# How do you configure a Spring bean container to load a Java property file?

Tags: java, spring, properties, classpath

How do you configure a Spring bean container (or application context) to load a Java property file?

[JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/) article [*Smartly Load Your Properties*](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html) explains how to load property files from the classpath using one of the following resource processing methods in the standard Java library:

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream ("some/pkg/resource.properties");
Class.getResourceAsStream ("/some/pkg/resource.properties");
ResourceBundle.getBundle ("some.pkg.resource");
```

How can you do the same using a Spring bean container?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Spring Framework Reference Documentation (2.5.x)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties) gives two examples of how to load a property file into a bean container, one before the release of version 2.5 and a more concise way using the `<util:properties/>` function that was introduced in version 2.5:

Before version 2.5:

```
<!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from the supplied location -->
<bean id="jdbcConfiguration" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties"/>
</bean>
```

After version 2.5:

```
<!-- creates a java.util.Properties instance with values loaded from the supplied location -->
<util:properties id="jdbcConfiguration" location="classpath:com/foo/jdbc-production.properties"/>
```

Note that in order to use `<util:properties/>`, you must declare the `util` namespace and schema location in the preamble at the top of your Spring XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

<!-- <bean/> definitions here -->

</beans>
```

Comment: Looking at the schema and the documentation in appendix A, apparently it does not.

Answer (score 7):

Your `beans.xml` file should have a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:some/pkg/resource.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <!-- Default values for backwards compatibility -->
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="name">value</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And then you can reference the properties as such elsewhere in the `beans.xml`:

```xml
<bean class="${blah}">
    ....
<bean>
```

For an article about this, check out http://almaer.com/blog/spring-propertyplaceholderconfigurer-a-nice-clean-way-to-share

Comment: Unlike the methods to which I refer in my question, function `<util:properties/>`, and class `PropertiesFactoryBean`, the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` approach doesn't make the properties visible outside of the context.

Answer (score 5):

For example via the [PropertiesFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertiesFactoryBean.html). Use the [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html) to configure beans in the context via properties.

You will find PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer examples in the other answers. Here is a PropertiesFactoryBean example :

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value=classpath:config/applicationConfig.properties"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Your answer was the only one to mention both `PropertiesFactoryBean` and `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.  Would you care to expand on the differences between these two classes?

Comment: If you want to inject a Properties instance as a bean then use PropertiesFactoryBean. Use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer if you want to parametrize other beans based on values of a properties file. I believe ProperiesFactoryBean is what you need here.

Comment: this is a subtle, yet very important distinction.

Comment: Yes, they have a different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

There's this thing called a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, you can use it to inject your beans with values from a properties file, like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:com/foo/jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
      class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Unlike the methods to which I refer in my question, function `<util:properties/>`, and class `PropertiesFactoryBean`, the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` approach doesn't make the properties visible outside of the context.

Answer (score 1):

We use this :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <value>classpath:test.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Which allows the properties defined there to be used as references in the config files

For more info see :

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html

Comment: Unlike the methods to which I refer in my question, function `<util:properties/>`, and class `PropertiesFactoryBean`, the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` approach doesn't make the properties visible outside of the context.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference the object as an instance of `java.util.Properties`, you should do the following:

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound"><value>true</value></property>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:property-file.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This allows you to reference the Spring bean `properties` as an instance of `java.util.Properties`. You can even have it merge together multiple properties files by adding more values to `location`. See this description of [resource strings](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-resource-strings) for information about what types of values Spring will accept for location. If you are wanting to use `${}` style substitutions in the Spring XML, you can see there are a number of other answers describing how to do that.

Comment: This solution is closer to the methods to which I refer in my question and behaves similar to function `<util:properties/>`.