# Does Spring supports nested SpEL expressions?

Tags: java, spring

This is my properties file:

`base1.jdbc.password=pass1
 base2.jdbc.password=pass2
 base3.jdbc.password=pass3`.

I have an environment variable called **%DATABASE%** which can be either **base1** or **base2** or **base3**.

How can i read the password property of the database stored in the environment variable? i thought about something like:

`<property name="password" value="${#{systemProperties['DATABASE']}.jdbc.password}"/>`.

but not sure if it's correct.

Comment: looks good. what is the error, issue or problem?

Comment: I tried it but i'm getting 
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder '#{systemProperties['DATABASE']}.jdbc.password' in string value "${#{systemProperties['DATABASE']}.jdbc.password}"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configuration in your application context xml

```
<bean 
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>##YOUR PROPERTIES FILE NAME###</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

You can get the details from an associated question ([How do you configure a Spring bean container to load a Java property file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975431/how-do-you-configure-a-spring-bean-container-to-load-a-java-property-file))

The description of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer is given here(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html)

Use the name of the properties file that you have in the `<value>` tag

Following is an example of how I have used the properties in my sample project. I have a bean called processRetryPolicy with the properties with are loaded from the properties file.

```
<bean id='processRetryPolicy' class='com.poc.process.model.ProcessRetryPolicy' >
    <property name="isActive" value="${process.executor.conn.retry.policy.isActive}"/>
    <property name="intervalType" value="${process.executor.conn.retry.interval.type}"/>
    <property name="intervalvalue" value="${process.executor.conn.retry.interval.value}"/>
    <property name="retryPolicy" value="${process.executor.conn.retry.default.policy}"/>
</bean>
```

The properties are defined in the properties file as

```
process.executor.conn.retry.policy.isActive = true
process.executor.conn.retry.interval.type = HOUR
process.executor.conn.retry.interval.value = 1
process.executor.conn.retry.default.policy = Retry
```

To add the environment properties I had used the following in one of the spring batch applications:-

```
<property name="environment" value="#{jobParameters['env.type']}"/>
```

The environment type was being passed as a runtime parameter as follows

```
java -Xmx12288m -D<<List of Params and Values>> env.type=$env
```

Another way of doing it in spring core is using the spring expression language (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)

Your expression looks correct.

Comment: Hello Amal, Thank you for you response, but please read my question carefully i think you didn't got it.

Comment: @oualidqannouf My bad! I misinterpreted your question. Anyway, I have added the details of the expression language and your expression in the question looks correct. The information may not be completely relevant to the question, but I am not deleting the answer as it may help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Add property place holder

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
 <property name="locations">
 <list>
 <value>classpath:xxxxx.properties</value>
 </list>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Then

```
<bean id="bean" class="xxx.class">
 <property name="password" value="#{systemProperties['DATABASE']}.jdbc.password"/>     
</bean>
```